# Every Lebesgue measurable function with bounded support is nearly bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function over the (non extended) reals with bounded support. I was wondering if we can say that, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a bounded function $g$ such that $f = g$ except a set of measure $\epsilon$. I think that using Lusin theorem we got that $f$ is nearly continuous but i got stucked in proving the nearly bounddeness of that function

Comment: So: given $\epsilon$ there is a continuous function $g$ so that $f=g$ except on a set of measure zero.  If interval $[a,b]$ contains the support of $f$, show that $g$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.  Of course you still have to consider the complement of $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

You could let $E_n = \{x : |f(x)| \ge n\}$. Then $E_1 \supset E_2 \supset E_3 \supset \cdots$, and since $f$ has bounded support each $E_n$ satisfies $|E_n| < \infty$.  Can you show that $|E_n| < \epsilon$ for some index $n$? If so just let $g(x) = f(x) \chi_{E_n}(x)$.